# how to combine "-" and "--" options when starting octave?

Tags: octave

I noticed that I can't combine `--traditional` options with the other one letter other options such as `-i` for example.

For example, when I have this as the first line in my octave .m file

```
#!/usr/bin/octave  --traditional
```

Then it work. Octave starts ok and runs the script.

But when I try

```
#!/usr/bin/octave  --traditional --silent --norc --interactive
```

It does not work. Error from octave. does not understand the options.

When I try

```
#!/usr/bin/octave  --traditional -qfi
```

Also error.  But this

```
#!/usr/bin/octave  -qfi
```

works.

The problem is that `--traditional` does not have a one letter short cut like all the other options. This is the options I see

```
Options:

  --debug, -d             Enter parser debugging mode.
  --doc-cache-file FILE   Use doc cache file FILE.
  --echo-commands, -x     Echo commands as they are executed.
  --eval CODE             Evaluate CODE.  Exit when done unless --persist.
  --exec-path PATH        Set path for executing subprograms.
  --help, -h, -?          Print short help message and exit.
  --image-path PATH       Add PATH to head of image search path.
  --info-file FILE        Use top-level info file FILE.
  --info-program PROGRAM  Use PROGRAM for reading info files.
  --interactive, -i       Force interactive behavior.
  --line-editing          Force readline use for command-line editing.
  --no-history, -H        Don't save commands to the history list
  --no-init-file          Don't read the ~/.octaverc or .octaverc files.
  --no-init-path          Don't initialize function search path.
  --no-line-editing       Don't use readline for command-line editing.
  --no-site-file          Don't read the site-wide octaverc file.
  --no-window-system      Disable window system, including graphics.
  --norc, -f              Don't read any initialization files.
  --path PATH, -p PATH    Add PATH to head of function search path.
  --persist               Go interactive after --eval or reading from FILE.
  --silent, -q            Don't print message at startup.
  --traditional           Set variables for closer MATLAB compatibility.
  --verbose, -V           Enable verbose output in some cases.
  --version, -v           Print version number and exit.
```

I am mainly interested in running octave code that is compatible with Matlab, so I'd like to use this `--traditional` option to make sure I keep the code compatible with Matlab in case I need to run the same code inside Matlab as well.

Or may be I can "turn on" this compatiblity mode once octave starts using a different command?

I am using GNU Octave, version 3.2.4 on Linux.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is really an `octave` problem, per se. The Unix [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) notation in general is somewhat limited. I don't know the exact limits off the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure many implementations aren't happy if you add more than one option to the shebang line, which seems to be your problem.

Using a wrapper script is probably the canonical way to get around such problems.

To address your question of combining short and long options, Unix conventions don't allow for this. You could consider patching `octave` to add a short option for `--traditional`, if this is feasible for you. Alternatively, I'd imagine there's a way to specify the traditional behavior in the user or system-wide Octave configuration file, but this might not be that helpful if you need the script to work on systems you don't control.

Comment: I solved this by creating a wrapper script with "exec octave --traditional -q $@", being the $@ fundamental